# WHY DOES A URL NOT CHANGE WHEN A LINK IS CLICKED?

Tags: hyperlink, web, frame

I ve been trying to link a website to another one. What i noticed is that the link in the website i want to link remains constant. Is it because of a frame? If yes, then how can i get the source link of that particular frame?

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little unclear what you mean by link remaining constant but you can get an iframe link in many browsers by right clicking on the iframe content and selecting an iframe option. For example Safari will let you load a frame in a new window which will give you the URL. Chrome will let you view the source which also shows the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Iframe will never show up the actual address, the container would show always the URL.